# How to add param to serialized object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a variable with a serialized strung:

```
var formData = $(th).closest('form').serialize();
```

How add param `'url' : 'true'` to `formData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serialized form is that of a query string, so you can just add the parameter by string concatenation:

```
formData += (formData.length ? "&" : "") + "url=true";
```

In this case, it's not necessary to encode the parameter name or value because they're free from special characters. In general however you'd want to encode them:

```
formData += (formData.length ? "&" : "") +
    encodeURIComponent(parameterName) + "=" +
    encodeURIComponent(parameterValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.serialize()` gives a string meant for a GET request, so you can just add `&url=true` to the end of it:

```
var formData = $(th).closest('form').serialize() + '&url=true';
```

Comment: I tried: formData + '&url=true'; But at headers HTTP I does not see param `url`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var formData = $(th).closest('form').serialize();
 formData .="url=true" // .= will concate string
```